# upload a file in modal pop-up

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have a modal pop-up for creating users where I should be able to upload a profile photo. Is it possible to insert a file in a modal pop-up? I have tried implementing this but the "Browse" button for choosing the file cannot be clicked.
I'm working with .NET 6 Framework.
Thank you.

Comment: Let's see what you've tried

Comment: Input type file